# What is the proper use of the "Supported Framework" field in the NuGet Package Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am experimenting with my very first (personal) NuGet Server and packages etc.  I'm using the [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

In the "Framework Assemblies" area of the package form you can define framework-dependencies from a list of "Assembly Names".  The field next to it is called "Supported Framework".

Everything I put in the "Supported Framework" textbox fails.

**So my question(s) are...**

- What is the proper use of the "Supported Framework" field?
- What should go in there?

...things like that.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

If I put 'system' in Assembly Name...what do I put in Supported Framework?

Comment: Exactly! What are you supposed to stick in this field? Do we type this in manually? When I choose an Assembly name from the dropdown list, then type in net4.5 as Matt Ward suggests (below), then the Assembly Name box empties and turns RED. Uh, a clue please? What is happening, what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Supported Framework field should be filled in with one of the [short NuGet target framework names](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Common_Framework_and_Profile_Targeting_Examples). Some examples are below:

- net35
- net40
- sl5
- wp7
- wpa